# How to sign snaps

Tags: snap

I am creating a snap of my software and sideloading it to my devices; which works nicely. However, I have to add the `--dangerous` flag to `snap install` and I'd prefer to digitally sign these snaps in order to make the process safer.

I can't find any specific documentation on how to sign the snaps when creating them with snapcraft. I am obviously not looking into the right places ([snapcraft.io](http://snapcraft.io)). Could you point me to the right direction?

Comment: If you publish them to the store, then you don't need to use --dangerous.  Is there any reason you're not just pushing to the store?

Comment: We are not publishing the snap into the store as it is a private project (that it's not intended to distribute outside of the organization) and, also, the devices are not usually connected to the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add your key to your login in [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/), it will be signed in your snaps that are uploaded and published under that login.